# how to set two video side by side and first video 60% and second video is 40% using ffmpeg

Tags: php, android, video, ffmpeg

*I try following command.its working fine.but its set 50-50% video.
and i got 60-40%. please help me. thanks in advance.*

ffmpeg -i demo1.mp4 -i demo2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v] overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4

Comment: If the video widths are not already in the ratio of 3:2, the right video has to cropped. Is that fine?

Comment: can u explain me how to set height-width for above command ???